# Java is said to ignore extra whitespace. Why does c=a++ + ++b not compile without the spaces?

Tags: java, parsing, whitespace, operator-precedence, post-increment

In all books on Java, I've read that the compiler treats all whitespace in the same way and simply ignores extra whitespace, so it's best practice to use them liberally to improve code readability. I've found proof to that in every expression that I've written: It didn't matter whether there were spaces or not, and how many (or maybe I just didn't pay attention).

Recently I decided to experiment a little with operator precedence and associativity to test the precedence table in action and tried to compile

```
int a = 2;
int b = 3;    
int c = a+++b;
int d = a+++++b;
```

While the former statement compiled perfectly, the latter produced an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable
>   source code - unexpected type. Required: variable. Found: value.

However, when I added spaces: `int d = a++ + ++b`, it compiled. Why is this the case? Java is said to ignore extra whitespace anyway. (I have Java 8 and Netbeans IDE 8.2, if this matters.)

I guess this might have something to do with how expressions are parsed, but I'm not sure. I tried looking up several questions on parsing, whitespace, and operators on SO and on Google but couldn't find a definitive answer.

UPD. To address the comments that it's the 'extra' that matters, not all whitespace: since `int c = a++ + b;` and `int c=a+++b;` both compile, one could say, by analogy, that in `int d = a ++ + ++b;` whitespace is 'extra' as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Java Language Specification section 3.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2), "Lexical Translations", says (emphasis mine):

> A raw Unicode character stream is **translated into a sequence of tokens**, using the following three lexical translation steps, which are applied in turn:
>
> 1. A translation of **Unicode escapes** [...]
> 2. A translation [...] into a stream of input characters and **line terminators** [...].
> 3. A translation of the stream of input characters and line terminators resulting from step 2 into a **sequence of input elements** (§3.5) which, after white space (§3.6) and comments (§3.7) are discarded, comprise the **tokens** (§3.5) that are the terminal symbols of the syntactic grammar (§2.3).
>
> **The longest possible translation is used at each step**, even if the result does not ultimately make a correct program while another lexical translation would.

So white space characters are discarded, but after the "sequence of input elements" is determined. Section 3.5, "Input Elements and Tokens", says:

> White space (§3.6) and comments (§3.7) can serve to separate tokens that, if adjacent, might be tokenized in another manner. **For example, the ASCII characters - and = in the input can form the operator token -= (§3.12) only if there is no intervening white space or comment.**

Answer (score 4):

The syntax analyzer need to understand what you are writing.

The sequence of plus symbols is not understable from the syntax analyzer point of view if you don't put a separator between them.

Adding **more spaces** over the minimum doesn't change the result.

So both lines have the same result:

```
int d = a++ + ++b;
int d = a++     +     ++b;
```

Consider instead the following code:

```
int d = a +++ b;
```

What is your intent?

```
int d = a + ++b;
```

or

```
int d = a++ + b;
```

Also from a human point of view is not possible to understand without the extra white spaces.

Also if this code works for a compiler is not understable from a human point of view.

The sequence `a++++++b` without spaces is not understable from a compiler point of view because he is trying to read as much as possible characters to determine the token resulting in the sequence `a ++ ++ + b` that is not a valid sequence of token.

---

In any case my suggestion is **keep your code as clean as possible from a human point of view** so it will be more easier to be mantained, read, enhanced. So **use spaces when needed**, don't abuse them, but don't remove them if the resulting code is less readable.

Comment: What are the rules which the syntax analyzer is using, and why does `c` work while `d` fails?  We already know that extra whitespace does not matter.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the compiler try to consume as much as possible characters to have a single token.

Answer (score 2):

The answer which should be marked correct here is one which strictly goes by what the JLS says regarding the examples you have given.  This answer is somewhat speculative, but it starts with observing what happens with `int c`:

```
int c = a+++b;
```

This is being evaluated as:

```
int c = (a++) + b; // c == 6
```

So it seems that the compiler is assigning postfix operator, which has a very high precedence.  Now in:

```
int d = a+++++b;
```

if we try to also form postfix operators, we run into problems:

```
int d = (a++)++ + b;
```

The above won't compile, because we can't apply `++` to anything other than a primitive.  So, this fails at compilation time.

I can see the answer by @Daniel which quotes the JLS as saying that the longest possible translation is used at each step, which means that postfix will be attempted before addition, because the latter is longer.  This agrees with what seems to be happening with the `d` expression.

Answer (score 2):

The parser will consume [as many characters as possible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2):

- `a+++b` is parsed as `a, ++, +, b`.
- `a+++++b` is parsed as `a, ++, ++, +, b`

The former is valid syntax but the latter isn't.